# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when use jquery Dom

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom, laravel-5.3

I want to add a new  after another div. I use bellow jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function AddNewValidTimeEntry() {

        var html="<div class='row col-md-offset-3'> @include('Row_Modal_ValidTime',['divID'=>'rr']) </div> ";
        $( html ).insertAfter( "#FirstRowValidTime" );
    }
</script>
```

and my main div is:

```
<div id="FirstRowValidTime" class="row col-md-offset-3">

                        @include("Row_Modal_ValidTime",["divID"=>"qq"])

                        <div  class="form-group col-md-2">
                            <div class=" inputGroupContainer">
                                <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">

                                    <button onclick="AddNewValidTimeEntry();" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <label for="ValidTime" class="col-md-2 control-label" >زمان معتبر<span style="color: red">*</span>     </label>
                    </div><!-- row clock-->
```

and Row_Modal_ValidTime.blade.php is:

```
<div  id='{{$divID}}'>
    <div   class='form-group col-md-3'>
        <div class=' inputGroupContainer'>
            <div class='clockpicker' data-placement='left' data-align='top' data-autoclose='true'>

                <div dir='ltr' class='input-group'>
                    <input id='ValidTime' type='text' class='form-control' value='08:00'>
                    <span class='input-group-addon'>
                          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span>
                    </span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div  class='form-group col-md-4 '>
        <div class=' inputGroupContainer'>
            <div dir='ltr' class='input-group col-md-offset-1'>

                <select   style='direction: rtl;' class='form-control' id='day' name='day' required='required'>
                    <option   value='' data-hidden='true'>روز هفته</option>
                    <option value='0'>شنبه</option>
                    <option value='1'>یکشنبه</option>
                    <option value='2'>دوشنبه</option>
                    <option value='3'>سه شنبه</option>
                    <option value='4'>چهارشنبه</option>
                    <option value='5'>پنجشنبه</option>
                    <option value='6'>جمعه</option>
                </select>

                <span class='input-group-addon'>
                      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span>
                </span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i run my code, i see this error for my jquery line (`var html="<div class...`):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Where is wrong? what i must do?

Comment: @NewbeeDev, Can you tell me more details?

Comment: can you make jsfiddle so we can see live error?

Comment: What is the output of `@include('Row_Modal_ValidTime',['divID'=>'rr'])`?

Comment: that error occurs because the include creates a new line where javascript strictly dont allowed new line

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, this include all html code of Row_Modal_ValidTime.blade.php file in parent div

Comment: @narges maybe you trimming your variable `html` will solve that

Comment: @narges why do you use javascript when you can easily just paste the php after the `FirstRowValidTime` div??

Comment: @madalinivascu, I want to add some div after FirstRowValidTime div when a button was click.

Comment: @narges see my answer below

Comment: @oserk, Unfortunately I do not know jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Row_Modal_ValidTime.blade.php has multiple lines and multi lines strings are not supported in javascript, you can use template literals by replacing:

```
        var html="<div class='row col-md-offset-3'> @include('Row_Modal_ValidTime',['divID'=>'rr']) </div> ";
```

With:

```
        var html=`<div class='row col-md-offset-3'> @include('Row_Modal_ValidTime',['divID'=>'rr']) </div> `;
```

Note that this is not supported in IE browsers, check the browser support for this feature [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=template).

Comment: when i raplace that, i see new error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" of line  "<div   class='form-group col-md-3'>" of Row_Modal_ValidTime file

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class to hidden the div at page ready and show it at button click

Change the javascript, alter your templates as follows:

```
<div id="FirstRowValidTime" class="row col-md-offset-3">
//contet
</div> 
<div class='row col-md-offset-3 hidden customH'> @include('Row_Modal_ValidTime',['divID'=>'rr']) </div>
```

js:

```
function AddNewValidTimeEntry() {
        $('.customH').removeClass('hidden');
    }
```

Comment: I want add new div when click on button each time. but this solution just show one div for me.

Answer (score 0):

I edit `Row_Modal_ValidTime.blade.php` file and delete all newlines.